# How to WHITELIST our CUSTOMER's domain to our internally deployed Google Sheets ADD-ON?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

We have developed a small Google Sheets add-on. Due to some specific reasons and also because of the tedious verification process, we decided to deploy the add-on internally. For example, Company "Banana" (ours) wants to give an access to our add-on "FruitCutter" to our customer called "Pineapple".

The add-on works fine for our internal users. Everyone can install the add-on and use it. However, since we are planning to give an access to our customer, we want to whitelist the domain of our customer.

I have logged in with the admin profile and tried to add the domain to the whitelisted domains. But I don't think it is working as I expected.

Could anyone guide me on this domain whitelisting process? Even the documentation/support materials seem to contain this information, I could not find the relevant info to my case.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Refer this [document](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6160020) to know about allowlist which helps to allow external sharing with only trusted domains. Is this helpful?

Comment: @DharaniDharGolladasari Thank you for your reply.
I added a customer domain to the whitelist after seeing the document you referred to, but after the customer logged in as a customer domain, they couldn't find an our internal add-on in Google Workspace Marketplace and couldn't download it.

May I know the specific way for customers to download internal apps? The situation is empty and needs a lot of help.